# Gremlin query to find vertices which are connected in both directions

Tags: graph, gremlin

[Gremlin: Count connections ignoring edges with a parallel edge in the opposing direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46461428/gremlin-count-connections-ignoring-edges-with-a-parallel-edge-in-the-opposing-d?answertab=active#tab-top) In this question, I like to know if there is a way to find vertices which are connected in both ways from a given vertex. We know dedup() is there to avoid duplicate. But is there any way to find the vertices which have parallel edges?

Answer (score 0):

Searching vertices with parallel edges is a special case of cycle detection.

You can find the recipe for the cycle detection [here](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#cycle-detection).

A simplified version of the code to match your case:

```
g.V().as('a').
  out().simplePath().where(out().as('a')).
  path().dedup().by(unfold().
    order().by(id).
    dedup().fold())
```

example: https://gremlify.com/8c

Comment: I know the vertex from which I need to know other vertices that have parallel edges. I tried the below query, it is fine but when the connections increases latency will be increased. 
 {.    g.V(x.id()).out('label') .where(__.out('label').hasId(x.id()))    } Can you modify the query and explain a little the unfold part if I know the vertex.

Comment: If you know the start vertex you can just do `g.V(x.id()).as('a').out('label').where(out('label').as('a'))`, Note that this query will also return the first vertex if it is connected to itself

Comment: Yeah, I am able to this. I also tried      
 g.V(x.id()).out('label').where(out('label').hasId(x.id())                                                   
  and it works But is there any better way of doing this as you can see if outgoing edges of vertex increases the time taken for this query will keep increasing.